# CAKeyframeAnimation and audio sync

Tags: objective-c, cakeyframeanimation

I am using CAKeyframeAnimation to perform few animations in my app. I would like to play an audio file (sometimes during and sometimes after) along with the animations. How can I achieve this? Is there a AnimationDidStopSelector for CAKeyframeAnimation or is there another approach for doing this?

```
UIBezierPath *movePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
            [movePath moveToPoint:imageAnimation.center];
            [movePath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(839, 339)
                             controlPoint:CGPointMake(671, 316)];

            CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
            moveAnim.path = movePath.CGPath;
            CAAnimationGroup *animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
            animGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnim, nil];
            animGroup.duration = 0.5;
            imageAnimation.layer.position = CGPointMake(839, 339);
            imageAnimation.tag = 0;
            [imageAnimation.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:nil];
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is. First assign yourself as delegate:

```
animGroup.delegate = self
```

If you want to use different animations you can use KVC to differentiate between them:

```
[yourAnimation setValue:@"firstAnimation" forKey:@"animationName"];
```

Then implement this method

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag && [[anim valueForKey:@"animationName"] isEqualToString:@"firstAnimation"]) {
        //play your sound
    }
    else if (flag && [[anim valueForKey:@"animationName"] isEqualToString:@"secondAnimation"]) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks BartosZ. Do I have to explicitly call animationDidStop: method after `[imageAnimation.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:nil];
`?

Comment: No, it will get called automatically as soon as the animations has stopped.

Comment: If I have multiple CA Group animations, how can I have conditional statements inside animationDidStop: method?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this approach and will get back to you. Regards, Alex.